# How to serialize and Deserialize IGraphServiceClient client object?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We are working on a project which uses Microsoft Graph SDK to implement Excel/OneDrive related functionalities. We have a use-case where we need to serialize and deserialize the [`IGraphServiceClient`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/requests/extensions/GraphServiceClient.java) client reference/object.

We tried to deserialize the object but we're getting a `NotSerializableException` exception. We were exploring SDK and find [`ISerializer.java`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/serializer/ISerializer.java) class but unable to use it in serialization/Deserialization.

Could you please help us how can we get over this issue?

```java
UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = 
  new UsernamePasswordProvider(clientId, scopes, userName, password, null, tenantid, clientSecret);

IGraphServiceClient client= GraphServiceClient
   .builder()
   .authenticationProvider((IAuthenticationProvider) authProvider).buildClient());
```

Comment: This is a similar problem that I'm struck on. Hope there is someone brilliant folk, to help us out. Thanks for posting this question!

Comment: I was also trying to come over this situation but was stucked here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you'd want to serialize the client itself. For what purpose? The client is stateless and the token isn't portable so you'd need to deserialize and then request a token which is a _lot_ more overhead to accomplish the same thing as creating a new instance.

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur,  Is it possible to store authentication and refresh token and later use them to create a new IGraphServiceClient instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible and, frankly, there is no value in serializing/deserializing the client itself.

What you *really* want is to request the `offline_access` scope so that you'll receive a `refresh_token` at the same time as the `access_token` your using to call Microsoft Graph. You can then store the `refresh_token` string and use it to receive an updated/fresh `access_token`. You can then create a new `IGraphServiceClient` instance using that token whenever you need to make a call to Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for helping me out. I got your point on "serializing/deserializing the client". As you suggested to create a new IGraphServiceClient instance using access_token, I explored "msgraph-sdk-java-auth" but could not find any AuthenticationProvider class whose constructor accepts token as arguments. 

IGraphServiceClient client= GraphServiceClient
   .builder()
   .authenticationProvider((IAuthenticationProvider) authProvider).buildClient());

Comment: In the above LOC, I need to pass an IAuthenticationProvider object to build a client object. Is there any implementations available to get IAuthenticationProvider instance through the token.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IAuthenticationProvider as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        IAuthenticationProvider authProvider =  new UsernamePasswordProvider(
                "{clientId}",
                Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"),
                "{userName}",
                "{password}",
                NationalCloud.Global,
                "{tenantId}",
                "{clientSecret}");

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = (GraphServiceClient) GraphServiceClient.builder()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .buildClient();

        User user = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
    }
```

By the way, if you used Maven to install `microsoft-graph-auth`, there will be some issues. Currently there is a mismatch between the source code and maven repository. The source code of `microsoft-graph-auth` is fine. So you can download the [source code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth) of **msgraph-sdk-java-auth** and exported it as jar file. Use this jar file instead of using com.microsoft.graph.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT. This will work.

Another way is to use **Gradle** to install `microsoft-graph-auth`. This works fine.

```
repository {
    jcenter()
    jcenter{
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
}

dependency {
    // Include the sdk as a dependency
    compile('com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph-auth:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT')
}
```